# laravel testable store method with validation in basemodel

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to test creating a follower, however, because I am calling Auth::user()->id I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object". At the moment I have been building an input array and when I run the create method the validation is triggered from a boot method in the BaseModel. Is there a way I should mock the $input array or should I do the validation in the create method in my repository?

```
<?php

class FollowersTest extends TestCase {

public function setUp()
{
  parent::setUp();

  $this->mock = $this->mock('Convoconnect\Storage\Follower\FollowerRepository');
}

public function mock($class)
{
  $mock = Mockery::mock($class);

  $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

  return $mock;
}

public function tearDown()
{
  Mockery::close();
}

/**
 * Test Store success
 */
public function testStoreSuccess()
{
  $input = [
    'user_id' => 1,
    'follower_id' => 4,
  ];

    $this->mock
        ->shouldReceive('create')
        ->once();

  $this->call('POST', 'followers', $input);

  $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('followers.index');
 }
}



<?php

use Convoconnect\Storage\Follower\FollowerRepository as Follower;

class FollowersController extends BaseController {

/**
* Follower Repository
*
* @var Follower
*/
protected $follower;

public function __construct(Follower $follower) {
    $this->follower = $follower;
}

public function store() {

    $input = [
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'follower_id' => Input::get('follower_id'),
    ];

    $follower = $this->follower->create($input);

    if($follower->save()) return Redirect::route('followers.index');

    return Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($follower->errors);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mock the `Validator` behaviour:

```
Validator::shouldReceive('make')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(Mockery::mock(array('fails' => true)));
```

There's a lot of useful information on testing Controllers in [this Nettuts article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-laravel-controllers/). Jeffrey Way's book, [Laravel Testing Decoded](https://leanpub.com/laravel-testing-decoded), is also well worth a look.

Comment: My problem is that my test is failing because I am calling Auth::user()->id to build up my input so I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Laravel includes [a test helper method](http://laravel.com/docs/testing#helper-methods) to set the currently authenticated user.